# How to add Logout in oracle apex 5.0

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm a student with virtually no oracle apex experience, I created a custom authentication for my login system. 
However I have no idea how to log a user out, Everything I have tried has resulted in a multitude of various errors.
Would appreciate any help.

Comment: I am also a beginner with apex but my pages have logout button/functionality by design, automatically created by oracle. It is in the upper-right corner.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to Shared Component -> Navigation Bar List
2. Select the active list
3. Create List Entry
4. Place `&LOGOUT_URL.`in URL Target
5. Refresh your page and you should able to see the Log Out button on top of the page

[image]